# lme specifying correlation structure for three-level model

Tags: r, nlme, autocorrelation, mlm

I'm new to R and to multilevel modeling. I have a data set where I have a dependent variable `y` and predictor `x`, both of which are measured one time per day over a number of days within subjects. In addition, each subject is part of a twin pair. So in terms of my nesting structure, I have my measurements, nested within subject, nested within family (`FamID`). I expect my measurement values to be correlated over days within subjects, so I would like to specify an autocorrelation structure of order 1. Below is how I am specifying my model:

```r
m1 <- lme(y ~ x, 
   random = list(~1 + Subject | FamID, ~1 + x | Subject), 
   data = dataset, method="ML", 
   correlation=corAR1(,form=~1|Subject),
   na.action="na.omit")
```

However, I receive the error message,

> incompatible formulas for groups in 'random' and 'correlation'

Might anyone be able to help me appropriately specify this model?

Comment: You might want to tag with `nlme` to make it more likely that people with relevant expertise see this. In my experience, you can't have different formulas for the random effects and for the correlation structure in nlme.

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland says, the correlation and random effects formulas must match. See below ...

Simulate data:

```r
dd <- expand.grid(
    FamID = 1:3,
    Subject = 1:2,
    time = 1:10)
set.seed(101)
dd$x <- rnorm(nrow(dd))
dd$y <- rnorm(nrow(dd))
```

```r
library(nlme)
m1 <- lme(y~x,
          random = ~1|FamID/Subject,
          data = dd,
          method = "ML",
          correlation = corAR1(form = ~1|FamID/Subject))
```

Notes:

- `1|FamID/Subject` specifies "Subject nested within FamID", which sounds like what you described. Your current random effect specification `list(~1 + Subject | FamID, ~1 + x | Subject)` makes little sense to me: this would indicate

  - random effects of subject within family (i.e., separate variances for each subject, and an arbitrary correlation between subjects)
  - random *slopes* (effects of intercept and slope, arbitrarily correlated) within family

(the simpler `1|FamID/Subject` specification *does* imply correlation between subjects, through the shared family effect; however, this correlation must be ≥ 0, unlike the `1 + Subject | FamID` specification`. The` 1 + Subject | FamID` specification is also a little bit weird because it implies that the twins in a family are **non-exchangeable**, i.e. 'twin 1' and 'twin 2' would be specified in some way ...)

This is most likely overparameterized/unidentifiable (if you do want a random-slopes model allowing for the variation in the effects of `x` across subjects and/or families you can use `random = ~1+x|FamID/Subject` to estimate slopes at both levels — I checked, and this does still work with the `correlation` argument. I don't know if it's possible to specify random slopes at only one level (e.g. across subjects but not families) in `lme` ...

- `corAR1(form = ~1|FamID/Subject)` seems as though it might specify *two* autocorrelation parameters (at the levels of both family and subject-within-family), but according to the output (below) only one is estimated.

(Note that the random effects estimated are vanishingly small because I used made-up data with no structure.)

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: dd 
  Log-likelihood: -81.77192
  Fixed: y ~ x 
(Intercept)           x 
 0.08731064 -0.09266083 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | FamID
         (Intercept)
StdDev: 2.303609e-05

 Formula: ~1 | Subject %in% FamID
         (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev: 2.414397e-06 0.9598456

Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 | FamID/Subject 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
-0.181599 
Number of Observations: 60
Number of Groups: 
             FamID Subject %in% FamID 
                 3                  6
```